# How to columns into multiple rows in complex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    date      number  name  div    a    b   c   d   e   f   ... k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t
0   2008-01-01  150     A   get_on  379 287 371 876 965 1389    ... 2520    3078    3495    3055    2952    2726    3307    2584    1059    264
1   2008-01-01  150     A   get_off 145 707 689 1037    1170    1376    ... 1955    2304    2203    2128    1747    1593    1078    744 406 558
2   2008-01-01  151     B   get_on  131 131 101 152 191 202 ... 892 900 1154    1706    1444    1267    928 531 233 974
3   2008-01-01  151     B   get_off 35  158 203 393 375 460 ... 1157    1153    1303    1190    830 454 284 141 107 185
4   2008-01-01  152     C   get_on  1287    867 400 330 345 338 ... 1867    2269    2777    2834    2646    2784    2920    2290    802 1559
5   2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 74  147 261 473 597 698 ... 2161    2298    2360    1997    1217    799 461 271 134 210
```

to

```
date        number  name    div    a    
2008-01-01  150     A   get_on  379 
2008-01-01  150     A   get_on  287 
2008-01-01  150     A   get_on  371 
2008-01-01  150     A   get_on  876 
2008-01-01  150     A   get_on  965 
2008-01-01  150     A   get_on  1389
....

2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 2161
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 2298
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 2360
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 1997
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 1217
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 799
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 461
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 271
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 134
2008-01-01  152     C   get_off 210
```

I tried melt method like

`df.melt(id_vars=df.columns.tolist()[0:4], value_name='a').drop('variable', 1)`

but the column of 'b~t' is deleted... I want to add 'b~t' column is go to under 'a' column

It's not working on my dataframe...

How can I get like result?

`number` is train number

`name` is train name

`dive` is get_on or get_off

dataset is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Upb5PgymkPB5TXuta_sg6SijwzUuEkfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) after `melt`:

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=df.columns[:4], value_name='a').drop('variable', 1)

df = df.sort_values(['date','number', 'div'], ascending=[True, True, False])
print (df.head())
          date  number name     div    a
0   2008-01-01     150    A  get_on  379
6   2008-01-01     150    A  get_on  287
12  2008-01-01     150    A  get_on  371
18  2008-01-01     150    A  get_on  876
24  2008-01-01     150    A  get_on  965
```

---

```
print (df.tail())
          date  number name      div    a
71  2008-01-01     152    C  get_off  799
77  2008-01-01     152    C  get_off  461
83  2008-01-01     152    C  get_off  271
89  2008-01-01     152    C  get_off  134
95  2008-01-01     152    C  get_off  210
```